# How should I add a project to my github repository, should I change the project location to local github folder? Or should I do it in another way?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I created a github repository containing a readme, license and .gitignore. I haven't added the project yet, and I'm not really sure how to properly do this. The project is in my default projects folder, namely "IdeaProjects".

I want to add my project to my github repository. Should I change the location of the project so that it will be in "C:\Users\User\Documents\Github\repositoryname(\projectname)" , or is there another, more appropriate way to do this?

And how should I do this in the future? Should I create a repository and add the project to it afterwards or should I first create a project and create the repository from IntelliJ? 
There are so many options that I am kinda confused of what the appropriate way to do things is.

Also, should ".idea" and "out" be added to the gitignore?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you look pretty new to Git, I'd suggest these steps to work it out right away :

1. As you have already created a repository, clone it in your machine using **git clone https:url**
2. Now copy the src folder of your intelliJ project ignoring the iml, out directories.
3. Now, you are good to go with your changes to the repository. Use **git add . or git add src** to add the changes to your local repo.
4. Then use **git commit -m ""** to commit your changes to the local repo.
5. Finally push your changes using **git push**   { if you have a branch else use master }

You can refer to git tutorials to get a good idea regarding the flow, but to get confidence follow these steps.

If it is a maven project, you can directly import this project to IntelliJ and continue from the terminal IntelliJ provides. There are lot of other plugins to ease the process of git workflow, but to get knowledge, learn through commands. Hope this helps.

Comment: But the project wouldn't be versioned then, would it? And I used Github desktop, that automatically cloned the repository for me and placed it in /Documents/Github

Comment: It'll be versioned as its an initial commit {if and only if your repo is empty}. You can try it out and see it working :)

Comment: The repository already has some files in it, like readme, license and .gitignore.

Comment: They don't run into conflicts anyway. When you clone to your local, you wouldn't even see them. You can always run **git status** to see the changes you have made. Trust me it works fine if its an empty repo.